# How to add wpmode in Flash Embed Code in WordPress Site?

Tags: plugins, flash

I am very new to WordPress, and I want to Embed Flash in my website. I tried some plugin but it does not work. I consulted with some developers, and they said, I need to put, *wpmode=direct* as param in my Flash Embed Code.

How do I add wpmode in embed code. Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this plugin. [Anywhere Flash Embed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/anywhere-flash-embed/)

You can use ShortCodes like

```
[swf src="http:/:/www.example.com/my-flash-file.swf" width="600" height="300" params="wpmode=driect"]
```

This should help. For detail instruction, please see [plugins page](http://www.skmukhiya.com.np/anywhere-flash-embed/).